# EArgumentOutOfRangeException though nothing has changed the TList

Tags: delphi

I have another question about `TList` in Delphi...
I'm getting an EArgumentOutOfRangeException when accessing a TList, just the same way I've done before, after printing a different TList to console.

copy&pasted the original code below - did not change a single line

```
Writeln('c: '+inttostr(closed.Capacity)+' |l. 281');
  for i := 0 to open.Capacity-1 do
  begin
    Writeln('open: ' + open[i].startpunkt + open[i].endpunkt +
      IntToStr(open[i].kantenbewertung));
  end;
  Writeln('c: '+inttostr(closed.Capacity));
  Writeln('closed.capacity: '+inttostr(closed.Capacity));
  for i := 0 to closed.Capacity-1 do begin
  Writeln('closed: ' + closed[i].startpunkt + closed[i].endpunkt +
      IntToStr(closed[i].kantenbewertung));
  end;
```

The `Writeln('c: '+inttostr(closed.Capacity)+' |l. 281');` is clearly printed to console, the `for i := 0 to open.Capacity-1 do begin`-loop as well.

Console output is: 
c: 2 |l. 281
open: AC3
open: BC4
open: CD6
- and then there is the error msg

Is supposed to be part of a implementation of Dijkstra's alg. if this helps.

Does anyone spot a mistake I haven't? Or is this some weird special case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Capacity`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TList.Capacity) is not the same (and may be greater) than the actual [`Count`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TList.Count).

Comment: Yeah, too obvious. Sorry.
changed it to:
`Writeln('c: '+inttostr(closed.Capacity)+' |l. 281');
      for i := 0 to open.Count-1 do
      begin
        Writeln('open: ' + open[i].startpunkt + open[i].endpunkt +
          IntToStr(open[i].kantenbewertung));
      end;
      Writeln('c: '+inttostr(closed.Count));
      Writeln('closed.capacity: '+inttostr(closed.Capacity));
      for i := 0 to closed.Count-1 do begin
      Writeln('closed: ' + closed[i].startpunkt + closed[i].endpunkt +
          IntToStr(closed[i].kantenbewertung));
      end;`